# Subdomain to main domain file upload

Tags: upload, directory

how can I upload a photo from a form in subdomain (http://abc.domain.com/register-form.php and save.php is in the subdomain folder) to a folder in main domain(uploads) -> outside subdomain folder.?

Main domain public_html:
uploads
abc->subdomain location
index.php
....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does work if your two websites are on the same server.

I guess you are using something like this
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)

$uploadfile should now point to the location where you want to have the file.
For example $uploadfile = "/var/www/main_domain/cool_uploads/afile".

Make sure that the http server running the subdomain is allowed to write into the folder described by $uploadfile.